# C# Считать из файла и записать в лист каждую строку

Tags: c#

Вот код

```
using System.IO;

List<string> lines = new List<string>();
FileStream file = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(file);

//reader.ReadToEnd(); не помогает, что делать
```

нужно записать каждую строку разделяя ее по новой строчке

содержимое файла

```
111
112
113
//...
199
```

нужно что бы в листе было записано так
lines[0] = 111
lines[1] = 112
lines[2] = 113
и так далее.

Спасибо всем кто откликнеться помочь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

наверное будет так:

```
while (!readFile.EndOfStream)
{
    lines.Add(readFile.ReadLine());
}
readFile.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").ToList();
```

Comment: @pavel1787mego, вы уверены? Проверьте еще разок ;) В одну строку вместе с символами перевода строки читает `File.ReadAllText()`